# The meaning of random uniform sampling

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times n_2}$ be a given matrix. Suppose $m$ entries of $M$ are observed with locations sampled uniformly at random, is it implies that each element in $M$ is sampled with probability $\frac{m}{n_1n_2}$

Comment: It depends on whether the sampled entries can coincide or not. If $m$ entries do not coincide, then the probability is $m / n_1 n_2$.

Comment: @PinkRabbit If the matrix has duplicate entries, how to understand the random uniform sampling

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t mean the values of the entries, I mean the locations of the entries. In other words, if the locations are chosen independently in the probabilistic-theoretic sense, then the probability is less than $m / n_1 n_2$. **You need to figure out whether coincidences of locations are allowed or not.**

Comment: If the coincidences of location are allowede here, the $i+1$th sampling, then the left locations is sampled with probability $\frac{m-i}{n_1n_2-i}$  ？